How to re-use a single SwiftUI view as single instance in multiple screens?
In iOS SwiftUI instantiating a single SwiftUI view is pretty easy.
How about making this single SwiftUI view instance and its rendered content available to other screens in order to display the same view instance in a different context/view?
Let's have an example:
    import SwiftUI
@_spi(Experimental) import MapboxMaps

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Map()
          .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

Upper view may be part of a SwiftUI List. I'd like to re-use the same view in a sub-sequent child or non-child view in e.g. a GridView or any other SwiftUI view.
Once the SwiftUI view ContentView() is instantiated, how can this view be re-used within the same app, in a different context (e.g. alternate size constraints) as long the single instance (singleton) is existing?
Intent is to display 2 or more of the single view ContentView() instance without re-instantiating an alternate view ContentView(), according to singleton pattern.
SwiftUI by default supports re-using the instantiated views with various different data models. However, how to re-use exactly one and the same instance incl. its data model and other set view parameters in another screen without having the subsequent view elements to be reloaded or re-rendered? Thus, ensuring performance goal.
The support of passing view parameters to the ContentView() singleton shall still be supported.
Thanks for hint in iOS SwiftUI.

You are trying to achieve the exact opposite of how SwiftUI works. SwiftUI views are immutable, lightweight and ephemeral.  A view can only be a member of one view hierarchy. This wouldn't work in UIKit either, because a UIkit view can also only be a member of one view hierarchy.

@Paulw11. Thx for your feedback. I've suspected SwiftUI view concept not to support re-using a view in various context. So in SwiftUI, there's no way around defining/instantiating/rendering the identical view a second time. Thus, no chance to improve performance by design, except my own view design. A view like a map can be really resource consuming.

I suspect you are assuming that there will be resourcing issues when, in fact, it is unlikely to be a problem. I don't think you would be able to reuse view objects in any UI system. You certainly can't in UIKit or SwiftUI

If the view has property wrappers it can’t be done because of the value type nature of the view is static just put it on a variable

@loremipsum Isn't that basically the same thing as what I answered? That is, assigning an instance of a view to a variable? Just curious.

@AndreiG. your answer implies that any view can be put in a variable, my comment specifies that only static (non-changing) views should be put in a variable because they will never be synchronized. SwiftUI will make copies of the ContentView.

Indeed, I didn't mean that any view can be put in a variable, but only that it can be. Whether you should or not is a different conversation for which we lack specific context from the OP. I updated my answer with clarification comment. Thanks.

How about assigning as a constant and using that constant wherever you need?
let myView = ContentView() // <-- Note: Although this technically works, be aware it will be a copy of ContentView() which may not be desirable, depending on whether the view has static or dynamic content. See the comments above and below for more insight.

struct SomeOtherView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            myView
        }
    }
}

Obviously, you'd declare the constant wherever it would make sense. In the example above, it's outside the struct, but it might as well be inside it or in some other global class or singleton.

Views are value types, there is no such thing as a “singleton” because they just duplicate each other.

What I meant was that if he had something like a Settings global available as a singleton, usually something like Settings.shared, maybe this could have a property assigned to an instance of a view, like Settings.shared.myView = ContentView(). Would that not work?
Honestly, there was very little information as to the setup, so I just answered the question, which was how to use the same instance of a view multiple times.

Settings.shared.myView will give anyone a copy of the ContentView, they will never be synchronized.

For example, say you have a view containing a simple button: struct MyButtonView: View {  var body: some View {   Button("Button text"){    //action code here...   }   .buttonStyle(OrangeButtonStyle())  } }. Can you then not simply do let myButton = MyButtonView() in another view  ?

try putting a State in MyButtonView and change it, see if it is synchronized with other copies.

I understand everyone will get a copy, but what if it's static content that requires no sync of any kind?

Understood, if the view includes a State, it will not work. But if there is no state, like my button example above?

Yes, if the content is static (non-changing) it is ok. Because the multiple instances will show the same content. The OP wants 1 instance.

Your button has an action, it implies it will be changing something. I am talking like an image or a text.

And if the action is simply a navigation link to another view?

An action can't be a NavigationLink, but you would still be dealing with different instances.

The app I am working on now, has navigation actions in buttons everywhere. I am using the Routing library that allows you to navigate  with something like navigator.navigate(to: .settings).

That isn't a NavigationLink, that is navigating programmatically which still implies that something is changing. It shouldn't be in a variable because SwiftUI will be out of sync.

Just trying to undestand, how will there be multiple instances if you only instantiate it once?

The something that is changing is a path environment object. Would that be an issue?

Yes, as soon as the path causes a redraw you are out of sync, there are multiple instances because SwiftUI is making copies.

Interesting! Thanks for the answers, I will look into it further and try some of the above myself. I don't want to provide any misdirection or inaccurate information, should I delete my answer above then?
